# CakePHP get matches in an array() based on hasMany relationship

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

PlanDetails hasMany Companies. PlanDetail table has company_id field.

This is all I need to achieve: PlanDetail.company_id = Company.id. So get all Plan Details where PlanDetail.company_id matches Company.id.

Here is the query I have been messing with in the plan_details_controller:

```
function pd_list_by_company() {
    $this->PlanDetail->unbindModel(array('hasMany' => array('Plan')));
    $comp_id = $this->PlanDetail->Company->find('all');
    $result = $this->PlanDetails->find('all', array('conditions' => array
('Company.id' => 'PlanDetail.company_id')));
    $company_id = $this->PlanDetail->read('company_id');
    }
```

I cannot just get the results I need.. what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What you have shouldn't even parse. Furthermore, CakePHP does the joins for you automatically. What are you trying to `find()` exactly?

Comment: No matter what I do with this condition, I am getting a completely empty array().. with no results.

Comment: Wouldn't my $result at least display an array with data in it? I am trying to get an array of all Plan Details like PlanDetail.company_id = Company.id.. So if Company.id matches PlanDetail.company_id, a I would get a result for each... Does this help clarify?

Comment: Post your relationships for the `PlanDetail` model.

Comment: PlansDetails table belongsTo Company foreign key company_id . Company table hasMany planDetails foreign key plan_detail_id.

Comment: So you want all `Companies` that have `PlanDetails`?

Comment: I simply want to list all Plan Details that have the company_id (in the plan_details table) field that matches the Company id field of companies table.

Comment: **All** PlanDetails *should* have a corresponding Company, shouldn't they? Unless your data is corrupt. Are you saying there are PlanDetails that have a `company_id` that does not exist in the `companies` table and you want to find only the ones that *do* have a `company_id` that exists in the `companies` table?

Comment: deceze, Yes. All PlanDetails have a corresponding Company (company_id).

Comment: deceze, I did not answer your question fully. I want to retrieve an array of all Plan Details that belong to a specific Company. For example, Plan Details A, B and C would be returned for Company Foo. And Plan Details D, F and H would be returned for Company Bar, etc.. In other words, each Plan Detail is associated with a Company.

Comment: Have you got your associations set up correctly? You just said Plan Details belongs to a specific company.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a simple condition on the `company_id` field to me:

```
$this->PlanDetail->find('all', array('conditions' => array('company_id' => $company_id)))
```

Or, if you want the company as well and your associations are hooked up correctly:

```
$company = $this->Company->read(null, $company_id);

// echo $company['Company']
// echo $company['PlanDetail'][0], $company['PlanDetail'][1] etc...
```

You need to get a `$company_id` to query on from somewhere, which is usually the URL:

```
public function pd_list_by_company($company_id)
```

Then visit this action with the URL `/plan_details/pd_list_by_company/42`, which can be linked to using `$this->Html->link('foobar', array('controller' => 'plan_details', 'action' => 'pd_list_by_company', 42))`.

Complete example:

```
public function view($planId) {
    $plan = $this->PlanDetail->read(null, $planId);
    if (!$plan) {
       $this->cakeError('error404');
    }
    $otherPlansBySameCompany = $this->PlanDetail->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array('company_id' => $plan['PlanDetail']['company_id'])
    ));
    $this->set(compact('plan', 'otherPlansBySameCompany'));
}
```

Comment: This is what I have been doing: $this->set('planComps', $this->PlanDetail->find('all', array('conditions' => array('PlanDetail.company_id' => 'Company.id'))));..... And my sql_dump is accurate too: SELECT `PlanDetail`.`id`, `PlanDetail`.`name`, `PlanDetail`.`company_id`, `Company`.`id`, `Company`.`name` FROM `plan_details` AS `PlanDetail` LEFT JOIN `companies` AS `Company` ON (`PlanDetail`.`company_id` = `Company`.`id`) WHERE `company_id` = 'company.id' ..... But my debug(planComps) is always an empty array.. This makes no sense : (

Comment: Your condition says *"WHERE `company_id` is equal to the string "Company.id"*. That doesn't make sense. Also, if you're searching for *some specific company*, you have to plug in the actual numeric id somewhere.

Comment: But isnt  'company.id' supposed to read from the current find array() and attain the Company ID field value? The relationships are all correct.

Comment: You seem to have a wrong understanding somewhere. :) The `Model->find()` methods are mostly a wrapper around *SQL queries*. What you're formulating in your original question are just *three* independent SQL queries. You can only either get *all* PlanDetails from the database, or PlanDetails that have a specific `company_id`. In case of the latter, you need to specify *which* `company_id` at some point, otherwise you're simply getting *all* records (or none, since the query doesn't make sense). What exactly would you expect to get from the query in your question?

Comment: You are right. I do not understand a fundamental of my controller actions. I need to return an array of all Plan Details for a specific Company. And I am using the view() action w/ set() to pass the array to my view. I think what my main problem is I do not know how to extract the current company_id (for the current record I am viewing), so I can use that value in my query. But I am honestly a bit confused on how to achieve that.

Comment: My current controller code (not working as I need it to): function view($id = null) {
  if (!$id) {
   $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid plan detail', true));
   $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
  }
  $this->set('planDetail', $this->PlanDetail->read(null, $id));
  $id = $this->PlanDetail->field('company_id');
  $cid = $this->PlanDetail->Company->field('id');
  $this->set('planComps', $this->PlanDetail->find('all', array('conditions' => array($id =>  $cid))));
 }

Comment: Just change the call to `$this->PlanDetail->read(null, $id)` to what I have described in my answer. That's all you need.

Comment: deceze, can you show me a full code sample of your suggestion? I found another way to do it, but I think your way might be easier. I just could not get your method working. My working code is below:

Comment: deceze, I think that was my confusion, the Company.id was not being passed by the url - only the PlanDetail.id... So I did not know how to extract the current field values. But I was able to get it in an array and then use the set extract method to strip the value out.. I think my method might be more complicated than needed, so I would like to see another code sample if you have another idea. Thanks for your time.

Comment: deceze, I see your complete sample. I am pulling these records into the Plan Details view, and the url has the Plan Detail ID in my case, so my original question was probably not clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

I am displaying the set() find result in the Plan Detail view.ctp.

This is how I solved it:

```
    function view($id = null) {
    if (!$id) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid plan detail', true));
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
    $this->set('planDetail', $this->PlanDetail->read(null, $id));
        $cid = $this->PlanDetail->read('Company.id');
        $cid_extract = Set::extract($cid, 'Company.id');
    $this->set('planComps', $this->PlanDetail->find('all',array('conditions' => array("company_id" => $cid_extract))));
}
```

Comment: Yeah it was a hack for sure.. It works, but I like the simplicity of your sample..